# Flowtype.js Specific object targeting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does this line of code mean that the flowtype.js is being applied to all the type in the body tag?

```
$('body').flowtype();
```

I am new to javascript. If I want to have the flowtype target just H1's and P's do I just replace the 'body' with 'h1' and 'p'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('h1, p').flowtype()` should do it.

If you want to target a class, like `<p class="paragraph">`, you'd use `$('.paragraph').flowtype()`

Or, if you want to target an id, like `<p id="main-paragraph">`, you'd use `$('#main-paragraph').flowtype()`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: No problem! JQuery uses the same selectors as CSS, so you can basically target using the same rules, though sometimes there are better ways to find stuff, like .find().